# Kotlin Nullable Any

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am new to Kotlin. I am facing the following problem. I have a function like this,

```
fun updateAfterFind(updateColumn:Map<Column<*>, Any?>): Boolean{
    ExposedUser.update( {ExposedUser.id eq 123} ){
        for (column in updateColumn){
            it[column.key] = column.value
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The `column.value` is of type Any?. Still I am getting the following error,
[image]

I have also tried casting, `column.name as Any?`. But it didn't helped.

After doing `gradle build` I got the following error,

```
Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter S in fun <S> set(column: Column<S>, value: S?): Unit
None of the following substitutions
(Column<CapturedTypeConstructor(*)>,CapturedTypeConstructor(*)?)
(Column<Any>,Any?)
can be applied to
(Column<*>,Any)
```

Comment: What's the signature of `ExposedUser.update`?

Comment: @MattTimmermans `fun <T:Table> T.update(where: SqlExpressionBuilder.()->Op<Boolean>, limit: Int? = null, body: T.(UpdateStatement)->Unit): Int`

Comment: What type is `it`?

Comment: @smac89 `it` is of type `ExposedUser` which extends `org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature for `<S> UpdateStatement.set(Column<S>,S?)` says that the type parameter for the column has to match the value type.

You have a `Column<*>` and a value `Any`.  That doesn't match, because `Column<*>` is not the same as `Column<Any>`.  The `*` could be anything, so it could be a `Column<Integer>`, for example, and you can't set an `Any` as the value.

If you *know* that the types really are compatible, then you can override the check by saying `it[column.key as Column<Any>] = column.value`

The cast is gross, but using that `Map` to store these updates is not type-safe, and this is where you have to take responsibility for that.